# How to make a quick interface to edit / delete / add the database?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the database mysql.
I need to access it via a desktop application with the ability to change does not have value.

in asp.net is there, this dynamic data filter, I need the same thing but in WPF.

Comment: Justin, jastin wrote what I needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio has lots of easy tools to help you integrate your SQL Server into the application from using things like the DataGridView to the DataRepeater take a look at this article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfviews.aspx it should help you get started. Using LINQ to assist in speed application development.

Another Great link: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/wpf/WPFDataBindingWithLINQ.aspx